# Mock Verify/VerifyAll before or after Assertion

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have been used to following code pattern while writing my test

```
public void TestMethod_Condition_Output()
{
    //Arrange----------------
    Mock<x> temp = new Mock<x>();
    temp.setup.......

    //Act--------------------
    classinstance.TestMethod()

   //Assert------------------

   temp.VerifyAll();
   Assert.AreNotEqual(.....)    
}
```

I have been used to do the VerifyAll() before performing Assertions. But lately on some online examples, I have seen people doing Assertion first and then VerifyAll, if any. I do feel that my way is the correct way unless I am missing something.

Could you please alert me if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, the verify should come after the asserts.  I want the asserts close to the invocation of the method under test as they are documenting what the method does.  The verifications of the mock invocations are detailing how the class uses it's dependencies.  This is less important to tie directly to the method itself.

In a sense the mocking of the dependencies becomes a wrapper around the actual test itself.  This makes the test more understandable (to me, anyway, YMMV).  My tests then follow this pattern:

Arrange

- Mock
- Set up expectations for dependencies
- Set up expected results
- Create class under test

Act

- Invoke method under test

Assert

- Assert actual results match expected results
- Verify that expectations were met

I don't know that I would be pedantic about it, but this is the order that makes the most sense to me.

Comment: fair comment. Even I am tied down which way to follow. In my scenario [Verify before Assertion], it does make sure whether the dependencies are properly set and there are no issues with it. When my controller does some expensive db calls, it's important to run Verify before Assertion to make sure it is really mocked rather than doing those few assertions first. Either way, I feel both of our approaches are valid

Comment: @Nimesh - I don't see how doing the verification before the asserts actually helps with regard to ensuring that the methods are mocked before making an expensive db call.  Surely if they're not mocked, then you've already made the db call by the time you get to the verification anyway.  Once the unit test is passing it shouldn't make any difference.  Have I missed something?

Comment: No, you haven't missed anything. Yeah, once the unit tests are passed, it doesn't matter which order we use. But yeah while development, it will be useful. But, I got my answer, the order doesn't matter. Thanks heaps mate.

Answer (score 2):

In a AAA style testing I do not use VerifyAll but rather than verify methods were called explicitly as part of the unit of test. Within the Arrange area I only setup methods that need to return a value.

using Rhino as an example...

```
//Arrange
mockedInterface.Stub(x => x.SomeMethod1()).Returns(2);

...

//Assert
mockedInterface.AssertWasCalled(x => x.SomeMethod1());
mockedInterface.AssertWasCalled(x => x.SomeMethod2());
Assert.AreEqual(...); // stanmdard NUnit asserttions
```

I do not need to setup the expected call to SomeMethod2() if it does not return anything.

With Loose mocks there is no real need to call VerifyAll as calls to other methods would not fail the test (unless a return is needed then it is required in the Arrange section).

The amount of assertions should be kept to a minimum (create more tests if it gets too large) and the order of them should not really matter either.

Comment: I am using Moq for my mocking. But the general explanation and the order of them should not really matter asserted my assumption. I thought so but in best practice term, I would myself prefer verify before assertions.